# How can my marketing domain benefit from SaaS platform domain rating?

Tags: seo, ranking, domain-authority

I have a marketing domain that has 3,600ish backlinks. My platform domain (product site) has to 92,700 backlinks and a much higher domain rank (according to ahrefs.com). Is there a way to have my marketing site benefit from the higher domain rank of my platform domain? I have considered moving my marketing domain to a sub domain of my platform domain. Something like `https://home.example.com`. However, I'm not sure Google would prioritize my `home.example.com` over the other pages that the platform (product) uses.

I have also considered adding more links in the footer of the platform to point to my marketing domain. Not sure if this is advised or will provide any benefit. I already have a text link with my company name linking back to the marketing site.

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains are separate domains, so it wont help your ranking by making one a subdomain of another.

You can provide more links from one website to another, as long as they are seen as natural. I think the bot will figure it out if you put say ten links to the same site on page.